# Error: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have read the other topics and tried the different solutions but I am still stuck..

Impossible to launch my app locally. Juste upgrade from Ruby 2.6.8 to 2.7.6

Having the error message "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets."

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Error: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets.
        on line 8:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>> @import "font-awesome-sprockets";

   ^
):
    43:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    44:     <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    45:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    46:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    47: 
    48:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
    49: 
  
app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:8
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:46
```

I tried rake assets:precompile, restart the server ect = no result..

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you show head of `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file?

Comment: You said you just upgraded Ruby from 2.6.8 to 2.7.6.  This would require a new bundle install as anytime you upgrade Ruby and the version upgraded on the second number is higher it has a new gems folder.  Try doing a new bundle install.  Other than that we need to see your application.scss file.

Comment: This is my scss file : // Graphical variables
`code`@import "config/fonts";
@import "config/colors";
@import "config/bootstrap_variables";

// External libraries
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";

// Your CSS partials
@import "components/index";
@import "pages/index";

// Action Text
@import "./actiontext.scss";`code`.  ---  Just tried another branch, it works just fine... Any idea ? to understand what is wrong